# setTimeout function with Promise resolve value as a callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, es6-promise

I have this piece of code that really confuses me, so I will try to paste it here and write down by words how I think it is executed, it probably won't be correct so you can correct me.

```js
const wait = function(seconds) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
  });
};

wait(1)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`1 second passed`);
    return wait(1);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`2 second passed`);
    return wait(1);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`3 second passed`);
    return wait(1);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`4 second passed`);
    return wait(1);
  })
  .then(() => console.log(`5 second passed`));
```

So the part that confuses me is setting 'resolve' as a callback inside the `setTimeout` function, I will try to write step by step and you can correct me if it is wrong.

- Step 1: We are calling wait function and passing 1 as a seconds argument
- Step 2: Inside the function, we are creating a new Promise where we
  specified what happens only if the promise is settled(fulfilled), we
  don't care about rejection.
- Step 3: Inside the promise constructor, we have setTimeout function with resolve as a callback which will be called after a 1-second pass.
- Step 4: A second has passed, now our promise is fulfilled, the `then` method is fired. Since our 'resolve' is empty we can't use the `then` method's argument RIGHT? But still, then the method is fired after one second so we can use that to our advantage to log to the console that "1 second passed".
- Step 5: We are returning new promises so we can chain methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, your explanation looks good enough. Just steps 4 & 5 have a bit wrong.

> Step: 4 ....Since our 'resolve' is empty we can't use '.then' method's argument
> RIGHT...

The answer is NO.
You still can `.then`, and the data will be `undefined`

[image]

```js
var wait = function (seconds) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
  });
};

wait(1)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`1 second passed`);
  }).then((data) => { console.log("Result: " + data) });
```

Meanwhile, if you **return** the `Promise` or even any value, It still is value to resolve next `.then`.

```js
var wait = function (seconds) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
  });
};

wait(1)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`1 second passed`);
    return 999;
  }).then((data) => { console.log(data) });
```

> Step: 5 - We are returning a new promise so we can chain methods.

Actually, the value of the `new promise` will be the value of the next `.then` chain.

For example, Let's say the `resolve` inside setTimeout the specific value, then what's happened?

```js
const wait = (expectedValue, seconds) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(expectedValue), seconds * 1000);
  });
};

wait(100, 1)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(`1 second passed, Value = ${data}`);
    return wait(200, 1);
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(`1 second passed, Value = ${data}`);
  })
```

Comment: Really nice explanation mate you showed me a lot I didn't know I can do. First thing first about step 4, that's what I thought, I am newbie so I often refer undefined as if I can't use it since it is empty. Second of all inside first snippet you showed me that I can do multiple then's on one resolve. As of second snippet I didn't know that I can return a simple value instead of promise and chain it to next then handler. About third snippet I get what is your point but I think something isn't right there because both of resolves are fired at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Your explanation is good other than one minor point:

> Since our 'resolve' is empty we can't use 'then' method's argument RIGHT?

You can, it's just that it will have the value `undefined`. The result of calling `resolve` with no arguments is exactly the same as the result of calling it with `undefined`: The fulfillment value of the promise is the value `undefined`:

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
});

wait(200)
.then(result => {
    console.log(`result is: ${result}`);
});

wait(200)
.then((...args) => {
    console.log(`args.length is: ${args.length}`);
});
```

Note that even though we call `resolve` with no arguments, the fulfillment handler is always called with exactly one argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. About step 4, yes that is what I thought. I am still beginner so I am usually referring undefined as of "can't use it" or "it's empty". But thank you very much, great explanation.